# Variable as loop's expression

Tags: python, variables, loops, expression

Lets say I have string which changes according to input:

```
expression=True
```

or

```
expression="a>1"
```

How can I use this variable as loop's expression in the way, so I won't need to repeat myself writing double loop. (and without using eval)?

Well pseudo code:

```
expression="a<2"
a=1
while expression:
    print a,
    a+=0.1
```

would print something like that:
`1 1.1 1.2 <...> 1.9`

EDIT:
No, I don't want to print numbers, I want to change loop condition(expression) dynamically.

CODE THAT works:

```
a="b==2"
b=2
while eval(a):
    //do things.
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about ("loop's expression" ?!?). Care to be more specific, include pseudo-code examples, etc.?

Comment: "I won't need to repeat myself writing double loop"?  What does this mean?  Please provide an example of this "double loop" in which you repeat yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample code:

```
somevar = 3
expression = lambda: somevar < 5
while expression():
    ...
    if continue_if_even:
        expression = lambda: (somevar % 2) == 0
    ...
```

Maybe using [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms) might be the solution for your problem. And it's way better (more elegant, more bug-free, more secure) than using `eval`.

Of course, there are some very special cases where `eval` is still needed.

Comment: +1 for mind-reading. Also note that it can be parametrized (otherwise it could have... unexpected results when closures/different scopes of definition kick in) and that a `def` (i.e. fully-fledged function) works just as well (and is preferrable for larger chunks of code).

Answer (score 4):

You're asking how to run user input. The answer is `eval` (or - not here, but generally - `exec`). Of course this is a bad answer, but it's the only answer. And if the only answer is bad, the question is bad.

What are you *really* trying to do? There are few programs (most notably programming language implementations) that need to give the user this much power. Yours propably doesn't. Chances are you can do what you want to do without running user input. But we need to know what you're trying to do to suggest viable alternatives.

Comment: I knew about eval already, but as it were stated, for some reasons I can't or don't want use it.

Comment: @nagisa: I know. But it's the only answer to the question you asked ("how can I run a string as code?"). You need to narrow the requirements to "I got x and y as user input, how do I do z with it?". Or, if you really want to run abritary user input - well, that's `eval`, like it or not.

Comment: `eval` is the only solution but it is bad. At least use `eval(userinput, {'__builtins__': None})`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to change the condition of the loop dynamically, but you're not providing a very good use case so it's hard to understand why. If you just want to print the numbers between 1 and 1.9 with an increment of 0.1, there are easy ways to do that:

```
for x in xrange(10):
  print "1.%d" % i
```

is one. There's no need for this dynamic expression magic. Also, you seem to want the same value (`a`) to have two very different meanings at the same time, both the value to print and the expression that controls how many values to print. That's perhaps a source of some of the confusion.